# Text modification using RobotTools

Tags: notebooks, slideshows

I'm trying to create a presentation that will demonstrate the use of RobotTools. I'm able to get everything to work, but am not sure how to go about formatting text that is typed into a notebook (e.g., bold, italics, etc.). Here's a screenshot from what I've created so far. As an example of what I need to do, how would I italicize "GIF" in the second KeyType line? Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Needs["RobotTools`"]

nb = CreateDocument[{}, Evaluator -> "Local"]

KeyType[nb, "How would I italicise this text?"]
```

[image]

Comment: What is robottools?  I am not finding it in the Mathematica documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way that you can do this is simply sending the typed keyboard shortcut for italics (Command-I)

```
KeyType[nb,"Creating a  \[CommandKey]\[LeftModified]i\[RightModified]Notebook in italics\[CommandKey]\[LeftModified]i\[RightModified] and now not anymore"]
```

[image]

It looks as though `RobotTools` has support for using menu items as well, so you might be able to do it that way.

`NotebookWrite` might be useful for your purposes as well considering you can give pre-formatted cells to it.